# Android Notepad Exercise 1 tutorial and Menu.FIRST

Tags: android

Apologies if this ends up being a stupid question, but I was just wondering why this is done on step 9 of the Notepad Exercise 1 tutorial (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) ...

```
public static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
```

... and then `INSERT_ID` is used everywhere, instead of just using `Menu.FIRST` directly instead everywhere?

I was thinking that I don't want to create any new variables if I don't have to, especially when they are static final already.

Is it expensive to create `INSERT_ID`?

Comment: there are no stupid questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you used Menu.First everywhere then decided to move that option in the menu so that it was no longer the first item you would need to update all the references. This way you only need to update it in one place and the more sensibly named INSERT_ID will reflect the changes that you have made everywhere else.

As for the performance hit of creating new variables: Yes, creating the variable will use up a (insignificant) amount of CPU time, and yes storing the variable will use up an (insignificant) amount of memory, but you should never put performance before code readablity until you have determined that you have hit a bottleneck - you'd be in a very restricted environment for this to be anything near a problem.

Finally, a lot of compilers will inline the references to INSERT_ID anyway. This means that all references to INSERT_ID will be replaced at compile time with the value in Menu.First and the variable will never actually be created. I don't know enough about the Android compiler to say for sure one way or the other, but I would be surprised if it didn't do this.

Comment: Well, coming from Java Swing development, I didn't have to worry as much about system resources, etc., and I need to for Android development (based on watching the videos from the 2010 Google I/O).  

I actually was aware of the points you mentioned (though a good code editor can search/replace the Menu.FIRST to whatever new value you want easy enough), and normally I'm REALLY big on code readability, but like I said, was thinking that for Android development, the fewer variables I define/instantiate, the better.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I understand what @Martin Harris says, but I don't get why would I use Menu.FIRST at all. Couldn't INSERT_ID be declared as  INSERT_ID = 1;?

Comment: @prostynick Because it is possible that a newer version of the Android framework will change the underlying menu implementation so that Menu.FIRST becomes 0, or -1, or 456. This will probably never happen because too many apps are going to be hard coded to 1, but using the const gives you readability (INSERT_ID is the first item in the menu,  not "1" which may be the first or second item depending on how you index) and risk-free future compatibility at zero cost - so why not use it?